# apply() does not work on Node.js eventemitter's emit() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The apply() method does not work on Node's eventemitter's `emit` function.

I execute these 2 statements:

```
this._baseEmitter.emit('activity', {test: 'zever1'});

this._baseEmitter.emit.apply(this, ['activity', {test: 'zever2'}]);
```

The first 1 runs fine, and the event is captured by my listener.

The second one, however, does absolutely nothing.

Does anyone know why? Is the emit() function perhaps missing the apply method?
If so, I would think I would receive some error messages, but that's not the case either.

Comment: `var emitApply = Function.apply.bind(this._baseEmitter.emit, this._baseEmitter)` ...will give you a function that you can call like: `emitApply(['activity', {test: 'zever2'}]);` This assumes the `this._baseEmitter` context doesn't change. If it does, remove it as the last argument to `.bind()`, and provide it for each call.

Comment: You should accept @PascalBelloncle's answer, as it worked for you.

Answer (score 16):

Shouldn't the first parameter be this._baseEmitter instead?

```
this._baseEmitter.emit.apply(this._baseEmitter, ['activity', {test: 'zever2'}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct answer